# Nothing happens when I click the button for RadGrid export to Excel

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel, telerik, radgrid

I have a simple grid I'm trying to export to excel however when I click on the excel button in the command item display, nothing happens. Is this not automated or do I need vb behind it to tell it to actually export?

radgrid:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="Grid_Curric1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlCurric1" Width="700px" Skin="WebBlue"  CellSpacing="0" GridLines="None" >
                        <ExportSettings>
                            <Excel Format="ExcelML" />
                        </ExportSettings>
                        <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlCurric1" Font-Size="Medium" CommandItemDisplay="Top">
                            <CommandItemSettings ShowExportToExcelButton="True" />
                            <Columns>
                                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Growth"  HeaderText="Growth"  SortExpression="Growth" UniqueName="Growth">
                                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Efficiency"  HeaderText="Efficiency"  SortExpression="Efficiency" UniqueName="Efficiency">
                                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Risk" HeaderText="Risk"  SortExpression="Risk" UniqueName="Risk">
                                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                            </Columns>
                        </MasterTableView>
                    </telerik:RadGrid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need code behind to use the embedded export feature of the radgrid.
Try to add the page settings and may be also the pdf to check if it works with pdf:

```
<ExportSettings ExportOnlyData="True" IgnorePaging="True">
  <Pdf PageWidth="210mm" PageHeight="297mm" PaperSize="A4"></Pdf>
  <Excel Format="ExcelML" />
</ExportSettings>
```

If the above does not work, most probably your grid is inside an Ajax panel and this cause you export features not working. You should read [this](http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/export-radgrid-content-to-excel-word-csv-pdf-with-ajax-enabled).

Comment: The command item display disappears and nothing happens. If all else fails I'm currently just using a button to do it which is fine but this would be nice.

Answer (score 4):

My best guess is that you have AJAX enabled the grid, so it cannot send the file. Take a look here to see if this is the case and how to fix it: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-export-with-ajax-enabled.html

Answer (score 0):

Check this super fresh blog on the topic: http://blogs.telerik.com/blogs/14-06-27/new-export-and-import-capabilities-for-asp-net-ajax-suite. It includes code samples that you can try.